# Rails using one form tag for multiple actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm strictly looking for rails answers and hopefully a really good explanation on how it works because I've been trying for hours and can't figure it out.

What I'm trying to do is have a single `select_tag` but the ability to pass the parameter :number_of_cards, to multiple actions (whether the actions are in the same controller or different controller doesn't matter.)

sample code

```
<%= form_tag arbitrary_1st_path, :method => :get do |f| %>
  <%= select_tag(:number_of_cards, options_for_select(1..20, 2)) %>
  <%= submit_tag("1st_path")%>
<% end %>
<%= form_tag arbitrary_2nd_path, :method => :get do |f| %>
  <%= select_tag(:number_of_cards, options_for_select(1..20, 2)) %>
  <%= submit_tag("2nd_path")%>
<% end %>
<%= form_tag arbitrary_3rd_path, :method => :get do |f| %>
  <%= select_tag(:number_of_cards, options_for_select(1..20, 2)) %>
  <%= submit_tag("3rd_path")%>
<% end %>
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: I am no expert in Rails, but a form can point to a single URL. Then you can't  submit a form to multiple controllers actions at the same time. But your code seems correct as long as you have one form per controller action you target.

Comment: @Maxence I know its not a common practice to have a select_tag for multiple routes (or I'm sure It'd be easy to find the answer online)  but you misunderstood. it is NOT '"at the same time." the idea is that i have multiple routes that all require the same parameter `:number_of_cards` i want to learn how to have 1 form with multiple submit/get buttons where you choose one path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to use one form but have multiple actions.

## controller

```
def create
  @var = Var.new(var_params)
  @var.user = current_user
  if params[:some_action] || !@var.save
    redirect_to some_path
    # render :action => 'new' #(this method can also be used)
  elsif @var.save
    flash[:notice] = "Your var have been saved."
    redirect_to @var
  else
    flash.now[:alert] = "There was an error saving. Please try again"
    render :new
  end
end

def var_params
  params.require(:var).permit(:btn_name)
end
```

## new view

```
<%= f.label :foo %>
<%= f.text_field :foo %>

<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.submit 'Save' %>
  <%= f.submit "Some action", btn_name: "some_action"  %>
</div>
```

Using this method you can potentially use one form such as a select_tag on a page to pass a parameter to one controller action that is essentially rerouting you depending on which submit button you press.